# Why doesn't this code for counting the number of words of each length work?

Tags: c, file, text

> Count the number of words of each length in a given text file.
>   A word is any substring of any symbols except for space and end of line. The substring that is a word must be bounded by a space, end of line, or end of file.

**I don't understand why and where my program doesn't work.** In our automatic testing system, the program below passes eight tests out of twenty (you can't see the tests).

The output must be:

length of a word - number of words of this length in the text

each on a new line in an increasing order. If the number of words of this length is zero, we don't need to print it. The output must be written into a file.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

long int c[99999];
int main() {
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *output;
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    char state = 0;
    int s;
    long int l = 0;
    for (s = fgetc(input); (s != EOF); s = fgetc(input)) {
        if (((s == '\n') || (s == '\0') || (s == ' ')) && (state == 1)) { c[l]++; l = 0; state = 0; }
        if (!((s == '\n') || (s == '\0') || (s == ' ')) && (state == 1)) l++;
        if (!((s == '\n') || (s == '\0') || (s == ' ')) && (state == 0)) {state = 1; l++;}
    }
    if ((s == EOF) && (state == 1)) c[l]++;
    for (int i = 1; i < 99999; i++) if (c[i] > 0) fprintf(output, "%d - %d\n", i, c[i]);
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May be along with `\n`, you need to take care of `\t` also. It is not clear in the question though.

Comment: Without knowing the test requirements, this question leaves too much open to guesswork. For example, a very pedantic reading of the question could be construed to allow NULL characters in a the definition of a word.

Comment: @MayurK I am sorry, would it be okay to ask you why do we need to take care of tabs if we are already taking care of spaces? Aren't tabs just four spaces?

Comment: @fragileradius No; it's become common practice for IDEs to do that because actual tabs look very different editor to editor. For consistency, looks,etc, the community started moving to space-replaced tab that is usually, but not always, 4 spaces.

Comment: @fragileradius Space and tab are different characters and have different ASCII value.

Comment: @fragileradius My solution is just a guess work. And I can not provide proof that your program will always work just by that. So I don't think it is a good idea to post that as answer :) But I am glad it worked for you :)